# brightness-contrast does not operate on indexed layers

Tags: gimp

I want to darken a PNG image in GIMP. I open it and choose `Colors | Brightness-Contrast`. The application responds with the error message - "brightness-contrast does not operate on indexed layers".

How can I darken the image?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Whenever we have an indexed image source (e.g. 256 color palette) we will not be able to adjust brightness and contrast with Gimp.

To still do so we will have to convert the image mode to RGB first (*Image > Mode > RGB*), perform our adjustments and as a last step reduce the colors to *indexed* if needed.

Color and brightness adjustments of images with a reduced color depth may however not give us good result.

Comment: Perfectly correct - up to GIMP 2.8, which is the current stable. One of the most notable features of the current unstable version (which will eventually be GIMP 2.10) is the ability of performing any operation with an image even if it remains in indexed mode.

Comment: I wish I knew this before I spent ~5 minutes doing that carefully-placed lasso select. =P